# Adding menu items to Main Menu for all users

Tags: control-panel

If I add an item to the Main Menu in the control panel how can I make this layout visible to all users?

Comment: Try this great addon: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin

Answer (score 4):

I am at the point where I will no longer design an EE site without [Zoo Flexible Admin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin). I can make the control panel much more client friendly and self explanatory with [Zoo Flexible Admin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin). And it’s great even just for me as an admin. I’m not sure how I got along without it before!

It lets you build a completely custom menu set in the Control Panel. And you have have different menu sets for different levels of users. It's really great.

Answer (score 2):

This addon may help you.
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-default-tabs

In the past I have done this by manually updating a column in the members database table.